# Generic Type Inheritance in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-generics

I am pretty new to Typescript. Please help me in explaining what is wrong with the below code snippet.

```
interface ICalcValue {

    readonly IsNumber : boolean;

    readonly : IsString : boolean;

}



interface ICalcValue<T> extends ICalcValue {

    readonly T Value;

}
```

Comment: At least could you give some details about the error you get when you try to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other languages (ex C#). Having two types that differ only by type parameters is not possible in typescript. You will need to use different names for the interfaces (fixing the other minor syntax errors):

```
interface ICalcValueBase {

    readonly IsNumber: boolean;

    readonly IsString: boolean;

}

interface ICalcValue<T> extends ICalcValueBase {

    readonly Value: T;

}
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGE4BsEDVsCuEAQnAM4oDeAUNcvclBHACYD2IWAnmmQHIEAtgCNoALmTC2bLMxABuWg0bN2nHqjIBlMFFABzCVJlzF1AL61QkWIhQZseQhAA8AFQB8yCAA9IIFjI0TBx8LCJSCmQaOgYmVg5uZDCiCTczcyA)